# Why is Xcode 6 Beta download so slow?

Tags: xcode

I'm in the process of downloading the Xcode 6 beta, and it's downloading painfully slowly, <10kb/s, and as of now is forecasting that it'll take 2 days, 20 hours, and 55 minutes and climbing.  Is there a mirror somewhere I can download this beta?

Answer (score 3):

Because everyone wants to download things from Apple right now. 10.10 Beta access, iOS 8 beta, XCode 6 beta. Their servers are under stress. Unless it's your own connection, but I'm sure you checked that :)

Comment: That is probably a good guess. Did you run a Ping to verify ?

Comment: @Buscar How would a ping verify this?

Comment: @GeorgeGarside you mean to say that a ping reply from busy server is the same as from not busy one

Comment: @Buscar웃 I tried pinging and I got timeout errors, don't know if thats related.

Comment: @BritishColour AFAIK it is related, try Pinging Google.

Comment: Pinging is related, but not a definite solution in case pinging works. But if you get timeout errors, you know something is wrong. Server-side or client site, but you can rule out the last one by pinging google. If that works fine, the server is indeed busy. Give it a couple of hours, let it run overnight or try again tomorrow. Everyone is downloading it right now

Comment: @Buscar No, I mean could you clarify how pinging a server 'verifies' that the server is overloaded and this is causing the slow download speed?

Comment: @GeorgeGarside as you well know normaly the Ping do not overload a server. However if the server is extremely busy (overcapacity) the Pint reply time would be in hundreds not in tens, or it will Ping out. It is a very crude way I know, but a bench mark.

Comment: I had pinged Google and got ~20ms

Comment: 1st) Ping might be dropped. 2nd) Ping might be prioritized. 3rd) The pong might come from a different machine than you addressed it to. Ping is only meaningful to you if you control the entire path.